# Pyramid returning wrong Content-Type HTTP header for static assets

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi, pyramid

Up till now, I have been using Pyramid to serve static assets from a folder inside the python package, as specified in their documentation:

```
config.add_static_view('static', 'myapp:static')
```

and loading them from the templates as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ request.application_url }}/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

However, I noticed that Chrome spits out warnings like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type apache/2.2.14: "http://mydomain.com/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
```

or

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://mydomain.com/static/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
```

This happens on hard refresh, and it seems that 3-4 ***random*** resources which are loaded in the `<head>` are served with the wrong Content-Type header (according to Pyramid docs, the header is determined by the file extension).

There is no pattern I was able to deduce as to how the wrong header is set. Sometimes, it is `text/plain` for javascript/CSS files, sometimes it is a path like `/static/js/something.js` (and this path is in no way related to the request URL), and sometimes it is the value of the `Server` header, as with `apache/2.2.14` above.

This is a big problem since when CSS is returned with a bad Content-Type, it is not rendered, and this breaks the entire page. I have solved this by catching requests to `/static` with Apache, and using it to serve the static assets, while letting all other requests go through to Pyramid. I no longer see the bad MIME type warnings in Chrome. However, I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue, and whether it is a Pyramid bug, or whether I am doing something else wrong.

**EDIT:** I forgot to provide the specs of how I deploy my app. The production server runs Apache 2.2, and the app runs under mod_wsgi. The process I followed is almost verbatim described in this tutorial: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/tutorials/modwsgi/index.html. **IMPORTANT**: the issue only occurs when running on Apache via mod_wsgi. When I run the app locally on waitress, the Content-Type headers are always correct.

Comment: How are you determining what Content Type is being used?

Comment: I am checking the Network tab under Chrome's developer tools, and viewing the raw HTTP headers.

Comment: And if you serve the Pyramid app without mod_wsgi (I presume that is how it is served now), but instead with waitress, do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: When I serve it locally with waitress, I do not see this behavior. Forgot to mention that in the question, sorry.

Comment: So, then this is an artifact of the way you serve your app. You'll need to include details about that in your question.

Comment: Can you check if the url is actually handled by Pyramid? By the way, why don't you use `request.static_url()`? This checks for the correct view config.

Comment: What do you mean by "url is actually handled by Pyramid"? I know that the correct URL is rendered in templates, and the correct resource is returned, just the Content-Type is bad. And I presume that the requests were originally handled by Pyramid, since catching them with Apache before they get to Pyramid did resolve the issue. But you are right, `request.static_url()` is more correct. I'll switch to using that, although it will result in the same URL being rendered in templates.

Comment: I think this qualifies as a bug; perhaps you should report it at http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/list. They might now how to properly debug which component of your stack is doing it.

Comment: Why don't you remove the static view from pyramid and serve up all the static assets with apache?

Comment: What version of mod_wsgi do you use?